# I can't do my mapping In Azure data facotry with NULL values

Tags: sql, azure-data-factory

I have a problem with azure data factory
So they told me to do a mapping (i think that it will be a simple mapping) btw sql database tempory tables and a file source so my problem is that there is some colums( NO NULL) so i can't do the mapping if the colum doesn't exist in my source file or it exsist but NULL

below a table from my BD, for exmple  COmpanyTypeCode is empty in my file! any help plz? maybe i can use something to skip NULL 
thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can ship the null values of the source file.

But the solution is that you must specify a not null value to replace the empty `COmpanyTypeCode` column.

[Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview)  `[DerIvedCloumn][2]` can help you do that. For example:

Here's an empty 'null' column2 of my source dataset:

[image]

DerivedColumn expression:

[image]

[image]

Then mapping the columns in the Sink settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it 's works but just in i specify the NULL value, in my case i have a csv file with more than 5000 lines so ... THANKS

Comment: @DataGirl the expression will change all the empty or null values no matter how many rows you have in the Source csv file.

Comment: @DataGirl  I just not clear which is the source and which is the sink. I considered the csv file which with empty or null column is the source, the DB table is sink, the table column schema is not null, then you can follow me step.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ident flds like [FLD_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, they will cause this issue.  You can't simply delete the mapping.